# Not reload page when fancybox is open

Tags: jquery, timeout, fancybox, reload, fancybox-2

I'm french, sorry for my spelling mistakes...

I have a page containing a fancybox and i would like to reload this page all minutes except when a fancybox is opened. The page must again be recharged at the fancybox closing.

I use this code and when a fancybox is opened, the reload is not stopped and the fancybox content is always recharged.

```
var timeout
$(document).ready(function(){
   timeout = setTimeout('window.location.reload(true);',2000);
   $('.fancybox').fancybox({
      'beforeLoad': function() {if(timeout){clearTimeout(timeout); timeout = null; }},
      'beforeClose': function() {window.location.reload(true);}
   });          
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `beforeLoad` and `afterClose` works for me this way :

```
function reloadPage(){
 location.reload();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
 var timeOut = setInterval("reloadPage()", 5000);
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
  beforeLoad: function(){
   clearInterval(timeOut);
  },
  afterClose: function(){
   location.reload();
  }
 });
}); // ready
```

See [WORKING DEMO HERE](http://www.picssel.com/playground/jquery/reloadPagebutFancybox_19oct12.php).

Salut

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
$("<your selector>").fancybox({
    afterClose: function() {
       var timeout = setTimeout('window.location.reload(true);',2000);
    },
    beforeShow:function(){
       if(timeout){ clearTimeout(timeout); timeout = null; }
    }
})
```

Note: The version of fancy box is `jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.2`

Please check the [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/EWTxv/)

Comment: Thank for your response but I don't understand your's solution. It's possible to have an exemple ?

Comment: Thank you for your help Yadheendran. I finally used the code of JFK.